# Upload file in subfolder using move_uploaded_file in php?

Tags: php, file-upload, subdirectory

I need to move uploaded files into a subfolder where the subfolder is created at the time of upload using `mkdir`.

I currently have this code:

```
if($_FILES['updfile']['tmp_name'] != '')
{
    $destd = mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pms/upload_files/project_" . $id, 0777);
    $source = $_FILES['updfile']['tmp_name'];

    $dest = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pms/upload_files/" . $destd;

    //echo $dest; exit;
    $ext = strstr($_FILES['updfile']['name'], ".");
    $imageName = $_FILES['updfile']['name'];
    $destination = $dest.$imageName;

    //print_r($source);exit;
    move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the above code only creates the folder - it doesn't upload the file *into* that folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are adding the result of `mkdir` to the $dest string. That makes no sense. Just use what you give to `mkdir` as `$dest`

Comment: Please read [the manual about how to handle file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and to check for errors with uploads.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct location based on your code:

```
$dest=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pms/upload_files/project_".$id."/";
$destination = $dest.$imageName;
```